# Dashboard wordpress is empty

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

somebody else have created my web site then he gave me access to wp-admin page, but my Dashboard is empty i can't add anything. i'm a beginer so please help me, thanks

Comment: You'll be better off asking the person who built your site.

Comment: You probably got a "subscriber" role and not administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the account you're logged into. If you're not seeing much but you can login, high chance you're not an admin.

If you're only seeing a white page after logging in, then there could be a number of things causing the issue https://wordpress.org/support/article/common-wordpress-errors/#the-white-screen-of-death

Providing a screenshot of what you're seeing will help diagnosing the issue further.